# Problem installing double boot Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: software-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.  I have an older HP 120-1036 all-in-one. Originally Windows 7 upgraded to 10.  As part of install instructions, I'm not able to find UEFI settings to disable Windows secure boot.  Any ideas?

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: If originally Windows 7, it may be a BIOS only system. Windows 7 did not support UEFI Secure Boot anyway. Many systems also call it "Windows" or "Other". My motherboard said change to "Other" if using Windows 7, so that really is the Secure Boot setting.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to disable Secure Boot to install Ubuntu.
2. Your old computer probably doesn't have UEFI and Secure Boot.